# PHP to get password-protected REST datasnap information

Tags: php, rest, curl, datasnap

I have the following code to get some information from a DataSnap server:

```
<?php
    $username = USERNAME
    $password = PASSWORD
    $service_url = 'http://200.206.17.34:81/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/blogin/';
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $curl_response;
    if ($curl_response === false) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        die('Error occured during curl exec. Additional info: ' . var_export($info));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    $decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
    if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
        die('Error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
    }
    echo 'Response ok!';
    var_export($decoded->response);
?>
```

What I get when I run this is:

```
array ( 'url' => 'http://200.206.17.34:81/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/blogin/', 'content_type' => NULL, 'http_code' => 0, 'header_size' => 0, 'request_size' => 0, 'filetime' => -1, 'ssl_verify_result' => 0, 'redirect_count' => 0, 'total_time' => 0, 'namelookup_time' => 0.0002249999999999999938417316602823348148376680910587310791015625, 'connect_time' => 0, 'pretransfer_time' => 0, 'size_upload' => 0, 'size_download' => 0, 'speed_download' => 0, 'speed_upload' => 0, 'download_content_length' => -1, 'upload_content_length' => -1, 'starttransfer_time' => 0, 'redirect_time' => 0, 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '200.206.17.34', 'certinfo' => array ( ), )Error occured during curl exec. Additional info:
```

What am I doing wrong?

--EDIT:

I can connect to the address both with my browser and with wget.

Answer (score 0):

The data from curl_info indicates a problem connecting to the server, e.g., "'content_type' => NULL, 'http_code' => 0", etc.

Try inserting `print curl_error($curl)` before closing the the $curl handler in the first `if` statement to get more information.

Comment: I get `couldn't connect to hostarray`

Comment: Is port 81 open on the host? It appears to be a college and their security policies are usually fairly restrictive by default. Also, try setting the port number with `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, '81');` instead of through the `$service_url` variable.

Comment: I can connect to it from my browser, it's the PHP that can't, and doing that didn't work either.

Comment: Hmm..could be your server config. Can you connect via command line using wget and your login credentials? `wget --user user --password pass http://serveraddress:81` for unix; for Windows, substitute the `:` with a `+`.

Comment: It's almost certainly an error in authentication. Try explicitly setting CURLAUTH_BASIC instead of any authentication method. If you're behind a proxy, you may have to account for that as well.

Comment: You may find it worthwhile to test the various options via command line, then when you find one that works, convert to PHP. See the following resources for more info. [Authentication](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#Basic_Authentication), [Debug Tricks](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#Some_debug_tricks)